# Найти установленные программы

Tags: windows, windows-10, установка

Как найти все установленные в заданный каталог программы?

Каталог является подкаталогом несистемного диска, в разных его подкаталогах находятся установленные программы, но большинство из них устанавливалось не в текущей системе. Нужно выбрать только те программы, которые установлены именно в данной системе. Часть программ 32-битная (грабли для wmic product get).

Нужно получить список названий и путей к exe'шникам в виде txt-файла.

Comment: я что-то не вижу того, как вы пытались решить проблему, или значок админа ваш освобождает?

Comment: Ну можно попробовать поискать названия конечных exe в реестре.

Answer (score 2):

В Windows нет точного определения термина "установленная программа". Можно понимать это как программа, которая содержится в пункте "Programs and Features" панели управления, и может быть удалена средствами системы. Однако существует огромное количество программ, которые под это определение не подпадают. Еще заметим, что большинство программ включают несколько .exe и .dll, так что часто бывает непросто вообще понять где там "программа".

Можно определить это более широко как программу, о которой существуют какие-то записи в системе, но опять же существует масса программ, причем от именитых фирм, которые после удаления системными средствами оставляют после себя тонны мусора в реестре и не только.

Если исходить из того, что каждая программа содержится в индивидуальном каталоге (в противном случае концов вообще не найти), то алгоритм поиска может быть таким:

1) Проверить ссылки в каталог программы из подключей разделов `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\` и `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\`.

2) Проверить ссылки в каталог программы из списка `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID`. Ссылка обычно в подключе `InprocServer32`, но есть и другие возможные подключи, так что надо смотреть все.

3) Через интерфейс `IShellLink`компонента `CLSID_ShellLink` загрузить и распарсить все файлы .lnk в деревьях каталогов `c:\ProgramData\Desktop\`, `c:\Users\<user>\Desktop\`, `c:\ProgramData\Start Menu\` и `c:\Users\<user>\Start Menu\`. Конкретно нужно вызывать метод `GetPath` и смотреть путь исполняемого файла.

Это самые важные признаки - программы, которые внесли себя в список Uninstall, или имеют зарегистрированные COM-серверы, или имеют доступные ярлыки, безусловно относятся к категории "установленных". Для поиска программ, "установленных" в более широком смысле, нужно идти дальше:

4) Проверить прочие ключи `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` опять же на ссылку в каталог программы. В основном там ищутся зарегистрированные расширения файлов, но могут быть и прочие ссылки.

5) В разделах `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\` и `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\` ищутся подключи 1-го или 2-го уровней, совпадающие с именем какого-либо из .exe файлов в каталоге программы. Нет гарантии, что раздел программы будет называться именно так, но вероятность большая.

В реестре могут быть и другие ссылки на программу, например, стоит посмотреть список исключений фаерволла в разделе `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules`.

Ну и напоследок

6) В подкаталогах `c:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\` и `c:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\` искать папки, совпадающие с именем какого-либо из .exe файлов в каталоге программы.

Разумеется, ни один из этих признаков не дает гарантии, что программа действительно установлена и доступна. Она может быть давно удалена. Сходу не припомню ни одной программы от крупных фирм, которая бы чисто себя удаляла. Оставляют после удаления практически что угодно, вплоть до регистрации COM серверов. Microsoft немного получше чем прочие, но тоже мусор оставляет.

Answer (score 1):

В PowerShell запустить команду (для поиска, например каталогов, содержащих слово `VMWare`)

```
wmic product get name,InstallLocation| Select-String -Pattern "VMWare"
```

Результат можно распарсить по табуляции

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\  VMware vSphere Client 5.5
```

В выборку попадут, разумеется, программы, установленные средствами Windows

Comment: `wmic product get` перечисляет только 64-битные программы.